# BibTeX references problem

Tags: bibtex, lyx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

I tried to add an existing BibTeX bibiography to my LyX document; it works fine when I add citations inside my document. But after compiling it, references are displayed as '?' in the PDF document and the bibliography list is not included.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Does [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number) answer your question ? If not, could you more specific about your problem, and perhaps give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem?

Comment: The article was very generic, I'm using Lyx and bibliography processor is integrated.

Comment: Did you run first latex, then bibtex, and then latex twice more?

Comment: I'm using Lyx (www.lyx.org). There is just one button to compile my document.

Comment: If you try with an empty, standard, document, add one of the bibliography databases that are included (e.g. `xampl`), add a citation and then compile with pdflatex, does it still not work? If so, I would perhaps ask on the [LyX Users mailing list](http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2). Not that there's anything wrong with asking here, but I'm afraid there aren't many experts on LyX around, so for some questions I would guess that there's a better chance of getting an answer on the mailing list.